# How to produce form validations in angularjs2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, formvalidation-plugin

I am trying to create a from validations in such a way that when form is submitted the invalid fields must be highlighted with red color but i am not sure where i am wrong can someone help me

my template,

```
 <form id="login-form" name="login-form" class="nobottommargin" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
    <p *ngIf="activation" class="activation">We have sent an activation link to your email</p>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-offset-2">
           <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio"  [formControl]="form.controls['type']" value = 'personal' name="optradio">Personal
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio"  [formControl]="form.controls['type']" value = 'professional' name="optradio">Professional
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['firstname']" id="login-form-firstnamee" name="login-form-firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name" class="sm-form-control not-dark formcontrolheight required">
   </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 labeltopmargin nopadding">
        <button class="col-xs-12 button buttonmeroon button-mini   nomargin" id="login-form-submit" name="login-form-submit"  value="login">Sign Up</button>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

My ts,

```
export class SignUp {
http: Http;
emailfailure: any;
activation: any;
profilefailure: any;
form:any;
constructor(fbld: FormBuilder, http: Http, public router: Router) {
    this.http = http;
    this.form = fbld.group({
        firstname: ['', Validators.required],
        lastname: ['', Validators.required],
        profilename: ['', Validators.required],
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required],
        repeatpassword: ['', Validators.required],
        image: [''],
        phone: ['', phoneValidator],
        type: ['',],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ng-invalid class which is added to your input, when it does not meet Validator requirements.

You can also display some error messages depending on your form state:

```
<div class="error message" *ngIf="!form.valid">Your message</div>
```

Comment: You will probably want to read [this documentation on the new FormsModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html).  There is a pretty thorough example of how to do exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple form validation in angular 2

```
  <form   #heroForm="ngForm">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
           required
           [(ngModel)]="info.name" name="name"
           #name="ngModel" >
    <span *ngIf="!name.valid && !name.pristine" style="color:red;">   <span>name is Required</span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="alterEgo">Alter Ego</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alterEgo"
           [(ngModel)]="info.age" name="alterEgo" >
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="enter()">ENTER</button>
```