# Form is not getting displayed when the values are empty

Tags: angular, typescript

My template is not displaying when my details is empty but it is getting displayed when the details has values.I have been structed here and not able to find solution.Can someone please help me..........
My html,

```
<div  class = "nopadding col-sm-12">
<form  class="nobottommargin"   [formGroup]="form"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" name="template-contactform">
<div class="col-sm-12 nopadding socialaddress">
    <div class="col-sm-12 formpaddingcss">
       <h3 class = "headingfontcss">SOCIAL ADDRESS</h3>
     </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-12 formpaddingcss cardbackgroundcolor">
            <div class="col-sm-7 cardtopbottompadding noleftpadding">
                <div class="col-sm-12 nopadding">
                   <label for="template-contactform-name" class="col-sm-5 nopadding">FACEBOOK <small>*</small></label>
                   <div class="col-sm-7 nopadding text-right">
                       <span  class="cardtextcolor" tooltip="Log in to your facebook account and click on your profile, copy and paste url from there" [tooltipDisabled]="false" [tooltipAnimation]="true"
                    tooltipPlacement="top"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i> What is my address?</span>
                   </div>   
                </div>   
                <div class="input-group divcenter">
                    <span class="input-group-addon noradius inputgroupaddon"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></span>
                    <input type="email" tooltip="Enter Facebook url" [tooltipDisabled]="false" [(ngModel)]="details.facebook"  class="form-control required email formcontrolheight" placeholder="Facebook" aria-required="true">
                </div>
            </div>
      </form>
```

My ts,

```
      export class Social {
      message: any;
      http: Http;
      details: IDetails[];
      form: FormGroup;

     constructor(fbld: FormBuilder, http: Http, private _service: GetAllList,public toastr: ToastsManager) {
    this.http = http;
      this._service.getList()
        .subscribe(details => this.details = details);
      }
```

Http call ts,

```
    getList(): Observable<IDetails[]> {
  //  console.log(this.id);
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            if(response.json().error_code ==0){
            return <IDetails[]>response.json().data[0];}

        });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I assume Angular2 throws an exception because of

```
[(ngModel)]="details.facebook"
```

`.facebook` can't be accessed when `details` is `null`

If you change

```
[(ngModel)]="details.facebook"
```

to

```
[ngModel]="details?.facebook" (ngModelChange)="details.facebook = $event"
```

or

```
<input type="email" *ngIf="details"
```

then it should work as expected.

Comment: Gunter,still my form is not displayed and will i need to make details = [ ] in my form?

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? If details is an array, then `details.facebook` doesn't seem valid. It would be `details.[0].facebook` or something like that.

Comment: This is my server o/p   {error_code: 1, message: "fail", data: []}
data
:
[]
error_code
:
1
message
:
"fail"

Comment: What about the array access problem? Why do you access an array like an object?

Comment: i cahnged my html like this [ngModel]="details[0].facebook" but still it says the following error  Cannot read property 'facebook' of undefined

Comment: What do you mean by "still". Previously you said you are not getting any errors. I don't know if `details[0].facebook` actually makes sense. I can't see from your question if `details` contains any data or if any of the details items has a `facebook` property.

Comment: Yes Gunter,my details has no data but the form is not at all displayed and i want an empty form to be displayed.I am sorry if i confused you....

Comment: If you remove (comment out) this input, then the form is shown even with empty data?

Comment: sorry i did not get it

Comment: I try to figure out what causes the form not to display. This input element is the only one that has a dependency on `details`. Therefore I assume this input causes your form not to display. To be sure it would be interesting if removing this input element from your template would show the rest of the form.

Comment: The from is displayed by removing input and also *ngIf="details"

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. We know the input causes the problem. But none of my suggestions fixed it.

Comment: No problem Gunter,i had another question can you see it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099090/how-to-produce-form-validations-in-angularjs2/39101583#39101583